# oracle 12c cursor_sharing alter multple sessions

Tags: oracle12c

Question:
Is there an equivalent to dbms_system.set_int_param_in_session that works for init paramters where the value is a character string rather than an integer or a boolean?

Backstory:
I've got a problem with a 3rd party application whose api's don't use bind variables. This causes high cpu and slow performance as the application issues the same sql over and over. (hard parsing)  I've discovered that setting the cursor_sharing parameter to FORCE improves performance, however there are security issues with doing that. The 3rd party application maintains many sessions (~30-50) So my current approach is to set cursor_sharing to force during the time the 3rd party application is doing its thing and then set cursor_sharing back to exact when it is done.  Kludgy? Yes, very.  We did some research and found the dbms_system.set_int_param_in_session procedure which seems like it would be an adequate solution except that it only works with init parameters with data type integer. Is there an equivalent for parameters with values of data type string?

Answer (score 0):

Though im not well versed with using dbms_system, based on the [info](http://psoug.org/reference/dbms_system.html) available for `dbms_system` package, i tried to use `add_parameter_value` at session level and ended up with following error:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
DECLARE
 sid_value VARCHAR2(10);
BEGIN
  dbms_system.get_env('ORACLE_SID', sid_value);
  dbms_output.put_line(sid_value);
  dbms_system.add_parameter_value('cursor_sharing', 'EXACT', 'MEMORY', sid_value, 4);
END;
/
show errorsSQL>   2    3    4    5    6    7    8  mydb
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20004: cursor_sharing is not a list parameter


SQL>
```

So, tried the following trigger based approach which sets `cursor_sharing` to `force` only for user `SCOTT` which you can change as per your requirement.

```
SQL> create or replace trigger csf
after logon
on database
begin
   if user='SCOTT' then
      execute immediate 'alter session set cursor_sharing=force';
   else
      execute immediate 'alter session set cursor_sharing=exact';
   end if;
end;
/  2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11  

Trigger created.

SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> conn scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> show parameter cursor_sharing

NAME                  TYPE      VALUE
--------------------- --------- ---------------
cursor_sharing        string    FORCE
SQL> 
SQL> conn system/manager
Connected.
SQL> show parameter cursor_sharing

NAME                  TYPE      VALUE
--------------------- --------- ---------------
cursor_sharing        string    EXACT
SQL>
```

Hope this helps you avoid setting the value back to original value.